# Does every kanji come from a Chinese character? If so, where can I find the origins of a kanji?

Tags: kanji, etymology

I know that kanji are borrowed from Chinese characters but are *all* of them borrowed?

As a Chinese native speaker, I am wondering the origins of modern kanjis. Most of them are exactly same as the Chinese counterpart, others are simplified versions of Chinese characters (like 聴 is a simplification of 聽 and 図 a simplification of 圖) and I know that this is due to the reform after WWII. But there are some kanji that I just can't figure out which hanzi they originate from. For example, 転 and 込. The former seems to come from 運 or 轉 but I'm not sure. Maybe I'm completely wrong.

Are 転 and 込 kanjis that native Japanese made up? Not based on a hanzi? But after seeing this [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/recent-creation-or-adoption-of-hanzi-characters-into-japanese-kanji), this is not very possible. Is there a way I can find from which hanzis did these kanjis originate?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there are a few kanji that were invented purely by Japanese people. Examples are listed in [和製漢字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97). Some kanji were reverse-imported to Chinese (see: [Japanese-coined CJKV characters used outside Japanese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese-coined_CJKV_characters_used_outside_Japanese)). But I believe there are also many Chinese-origin kanji that are in use only in Japan because they have fallen out of use elsewhere. So not all kanji that are unfamiliar to you are Japanese-coined.

Wiktionary has the information about the etymology of most kanji (although I don't know how much they are credible).

- 込 is a 和製漢字 and is included in the above list. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BE%BC))
- 転 is a simplified version of 轉. ([Wiktoinary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BB%A2))

Answer (score 13):

*Not all* of them were borrowed from Chinese. Some were created by the Japanese following the same methods (六書【りくしょ】), and are hence called 和製漢字【わせいかんじ】 'Japanese made Kanji', also known as 国字【こくじ】.

込 is indeed a kokuji. However, 転 is not a kokuji. It is a simplification of the traditional Chinese character 轉.

Here's an online dictionary for kokuji. Hope it is useful.

http://ksbookshelf.com/nozomu-oohara/WaseikanjiJiten/

Comment: I wonder if borrowed is a better word than imported?

Comment: @KyloRen Edited. Maybe you are right. 'borrow' is used for taking a word or idea from a foreign language to one's own language. But Japanese people did "import" a whole writing system, Kanji, to express their spoken language. Many kanji characters have different meanings in Japanese and in Chinese.

Comment: I am just thinking that the original writing system was once called , 借字 or 万葉仮名, hence the reason I choose "Borrow" in English as 借字  implies that meaning..