# Does a kanji with only a kun'yomi reading indicate a Japanese origin?

Tags: kanji, readings

Does a kanji with only a kun reading mean that it originated in Japan?

Comment: Can you be more specific in claiming certain characters have only a kun reading? (give examples). In my experience, almost of all these are characters where the on-reading is *rarely used in Japanese* rather than non-existent.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you mean by "only a kun reading". How do you propose to decide when a kanji does not have an *on* reading?

Comment: I received my answer in the comments.

Comment: It seems that all kanji are derived from Chinese characters, and none were developed strictly in Japan.

Comment: @JACK Apparently you didn't quite understand the answer you accepted. It talks about "kanji that originated in Japan".

Comment: @Earthliŋ, Apparently even kanji that originated in Japan have their origins from China. I assumed that since some kanji only have on readings then some would only have kun readings

Comment: No, by "originated in Japan" the answer means 和製漢字 *wasei kanji* or 国字 *kokuji*, which do **not** have their origins in China. The answer also gives an example. Also see https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97 as well as https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42248/1628

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80941/discussion-between-jack-and-earthli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears so. However, some of those kanji that originated in Japan (called 国字{こくじ}) also have "on" readings and not just "kun". A common example is 働{はたら}く  /  働{どう}

Comment: And there are also 国字 that **only** have _on'yomi_, like 線【せん】 "gland".

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi The classification of 腺 as an on'yomi is interesting, as it implies that the word represented by 腺 has etymologically Chinese origins, but I'm not too sure what this original word is. EDIT: Nevermind, the etymology is from 泉.