# What is the upper radical in the Kanji 悪?

Tags: kanji, radicals

I recognize the heart radical at the bottom of the kanji 悪, but I cannot make my mind about the upper one.

- Do you know the name of this radical?
- Do you also know of another Kanji using this radical?

I have some notions of Chinese, and I don't seem to recognize a similar radical. I have been told Kanji/Hanzi have been simplified differently during history depending on Chinese or Japan. So maybe there's a different simplified Chinese form for this one.

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/932/whats-the-difference-between-%E6%82%AA-and-%E6%83%A1

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call it a "radical" exactly, but the top part of 悪 seems identical to the kanji 亜, if that helps.

Comment: Yep! I'm gonna search about the traditionnal character 惡

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Do you know the name of this radical ?*

It is **亜【あ】**, which is not only a component (calling it *radical* is technically wrong) but an independent character that even has [a dedicated page on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9C).

> *Do you also know of another Kanji using this radical?*

Yes, and there is [a relatively user-friendly website to look up kanji](https://jigen.net/) if you read Japanese.

When you [search for 悪](https://jigen.net/kanji/24746), you will get its decomposition ⿱亜心. And if you put 亜 in the search form as "component" (部品),
you will get [a handful of characters](https://jigen.net/data/%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%EF%BC%9A%E4%BA%9C%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97?type2=1&rs=100). But if you see [the information page of 亜](https://jigen.net/kanji/20124), you will be notified that its traditional form is 亞, which is likely to be used in more (i.e. [non-常用](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai)) kanji. So if you look up 亞 as component, you will get [a bunch of characters](https://jigen.net/data/%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%EF%BC%9A%E4%BA%9E%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97?type2=1&rs=200). Here is the dump:

> 唖 亜        
>   鵶 閸 鐚 錏 蝁 稏 癋 瘂 琧 氬 椏 斵 掗 惡 孲 婭 壼 堊 埡 噁 啞 僫 俹  䢝 䜑 䛩               䃁             㰳                       㝞

Comment: Do you happen to know any english-japanese dictionaries that offer the same kind of decomposition into components? I thought tangorin did, but either they changed it or I imagined it.

Comment: @mbrig English-Japanese? If you mean you want an English interface, just try English Wiktionary. They have entries for most kanji, most of which are shown with such decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

The upper part of 悪, 亜{あ} itself is not a radical, but if you take the kanji 亜, it's radical is 二.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use a method that is based on dividing the Kanji into left and right sections, where in most cases the left half of the Kanji represents the radical (辺).

However, this method doesn’t usually work when the radical is located at the top, is surrounding, or only occupies a corner of the Kanji.

In conclusion, it requires (1) a lot of practice, (2) an intimate knowledge of the Kaji, such as (3) knowing its origin, (4) the order of its strokes, and (5) the Kanji’s interpretation in order to accomplish what you’re trying to do, and identify its radicals.

Hope the above helps :)